# Audio player without favourites

Tags: sound, vlc, music

Pls suggest an Audio player which runs in background. Im using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The audio player should not be added in favourites. I should be able to see only icon on top right corner. When I click the icon the player should open.

Answer (score 0):

I think Rhythmbox should do the job. Although it doesn't have any icons in the top-bar.

To fix this you can always get this gnome-shell extension [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4470/media-controls/) which adds media controls to the top-bar and thus giving you an option to play/pause, back/forward and much more.

This extension works with all media players, not only Rhythmbox, such as spotify, youtube, etc'.

Comment: Thanks. Will try and inform you